# Right way to initialize a pointer

Tags: c++

what is the best way to initialize a pointer after allocate memory.
my choices:

1:

```
Myclass* temp=new Myclass [10];
temp=NULL;
// ..some code..now I need to check if at least one element was inserted
  if (temp!=NULL){
    std::cout<<"The object is not empty";}
  else{
    std::cout<<"The object is  empty";
  }
```

2:

```
Myclass* temp=new Myclass [10];

for(int counter=0;counter<10;counter++){
  temp[counter]=NULL;
}
  if (temp!=NULL){
    std::cout<<"The object is not empty";}
  else{
      std::cout<<"The object is  empty";
     }    
}
```

Comment: Between the two, I would say the second. I don't think there is a single "right way" to initialize a pointer. Neither of your samples look correct.

Comment: I say neither are correct.

Comment: Both seem wrong. First one got a memory leak in the second line and the second tries to assign `Null` to a class instance, is that really what you want? Might want to clarify what your problem is or what you want to achieve.

Comment: "After allocating memory" the pointer will point to the memory. Why would you want to "initialize" it after that?

Comment: What purpose do you think the lines after the first line, in either block of code, serve?

Comment: If neither of the choices is correct, how can I make the 'if empty' routine to check if there is a value or not

Comment: The purpose was to execute the if routin below. I need to check if there is at least one element inserted @David Schwartz

Answer (score 3):

Both of them are bad.

```
Myclass* temp=new Myclass [10];
temp=NULL;
```

That is going to leak memory. The pointer returned by the first line is lost.

```
Myclass* temp=new Myclass [10];

for(int counter=0;counter<10;counter++){
  temp[counter]=NULL;
}
```

The line

```
  temp[counter]=NULL;
```

does not sound right. `temp[counter]` evaluates to an object, not a pointer. Hence, assigning `NULL` to it should result in a compiler error.

The line

```
Myclass* temp=new Myclass [10];
```

is good. It will be better to use a [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) or [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) to allow for automatic memory management.

After that, you don't need

```
temp = NULL;
```

or

```
for(int counter=0;counter<10;counter++){
  temp[counter]=NULL;
}
```

Comment: I think you mean a `std::vector` instead of a smart pointer. While `std::unique_ptr` is specialized for arrays, it is cumbersome to use and `std::shared_ptr` isn't.

Comment: @5gon12eder, I refrained from suggesting the use of `std::vector` since the question is about dealing with a pointer returned by a call to `new`.

Comment: The purpose of that initialization was to execute the if routine below. I need to check if there is at least one element inserted

Comment: @gustav2704, if `temp` is not `NULL`, it's fair to assume that allocation was successful and you may use the pointer to access all the elements you requested. It this case, it is `10`. `temp[0]` - `temp[9]` are all valid elements.

Comment: Ok but now if I skip the temp _ NULL statement ,how do i check if fhere was at least one element assigned to the array? How should the' if routine' look like?

Comment: @gustav2704, there is no way to determine that by looking at the value of pointer independent of the line used to allocate the memory, at least not in a portable way. There might platform specific ways to do that, which I am not aware of.

Answer (score 3):

By default a C++ `new`-expression throws an exception if sufficient memory couldn't be allocated, or if the object construction(s) failed. In the latter case the earlier allocated memory is automatically<sup>(1)</sup> deallocated. So, this is effectively a guarantee:

> *You either get a successfully initialized object, or execution doesn't continue after the `new` expression (it goes to a handler for the exception, or to `std::terminate` if there is no handler).*

Hence, the checking for null-pointer is of no value in the answer's context.

All this said, instead of using `new` to allocate an array, just use a `std::vector`:

```
vector<MyClass> objects( 10 );    // Initialized and everything.
```

---

<sup><sup>(1)</sup> Except if you're using a placement `new` allocation function that has no corresponding placement `delete` function: if that's lacking then an initialization failure will leak memory.</sup>